# CORS on cropper js while cropping only

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-livewire, cropperjs

I am using livewire's WIthFIleUploads trait for image handling. After a temp image is previewed I am using cropper js to crop the image. The images are being stored on digital ocean spaces so I am getting a CORS error while cropping. I have a digital ocean CORS policy in place. Below are some screenshots of my code.

Here is my DO policy

[image]

Here is my image tag with corss origin attribute (ref: https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs/issues/413#issuecomment-419896312)

[image]

Here is my crooper obj (ref: https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs/issues/413#issuecomment-419896312)

[image]

Here is my error, the issue is that the cropper object is getting a timestamped url which is not opening and causing the cors I believe

[image]

I want the cropper to work fine with s3 as it works with local storage

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.